# Error on running Sage

Tags: python, runtime-error, sage

I am trying to use Sage but when I type `./sage` I get a lot of errors like these, with strange characters:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sage Version 4.8, Release Date: 2012-01-20                         |
| Type notebook() for the GUI, and license() for information.        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
/mnt/dados/sage-4.8-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 1: ELF: not found
/mnt/dados/sage-4.8-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: 
: not found
/mnt/dados/sage-4.8-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: CE�� :�  2b���K�������qXj�: not found
/mnt/dados/sage-4.8-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 1:   
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I am using Lubuntu 11.10 with `Linux vaio 3.0.0-16-generic-pae #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 19:24:01 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

I know that there is a new version but it is too big to download now. So, any idea how to solve this? I tried google but a lot of errors like those appeared related to other problems.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you downloaded a binary version of Sage which is incompatible with your hardware. (I think that the linux binaries for Sage can be a bit finicky.) You could download the source code and build it yourself; the source code is a bit smaller than the binaries, typically. If you have a compiler (gcc) and other basic development tools on your machine, it should build in a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to discover if I have the correct version?

Comment: Well, you have `sage-4.8-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux` on (L)ubuntu 11.10, so there is that incompatibility, at least.  I, too, recommend downloading the source and compiling it; it should be relatively painless.