# Got Python error on FIRST run of a newly installed Sage 7.6

Tags: python, sage

I downloaded the latest Sage 7.6 binary tarball and unpack it. Then I typed "./sage" in terminal, after a long list of patching messages, I got this error message:

```
$SAGE_ROOT/local/bin/python: 1: $SAGE_ROOT/local/bin/python: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Does anyone know any clue?

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (64-bit) with kernel Linux 4.4.0-72-generic #93~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 15:06:30 UTC 2017.

The binary is sage-7.6-Ubuntu_14.04-x86_64.tar.bz2 and i have checked the md5 sum.

The output of `/usr/bin/env python --version` is Python 2.7.6 on my computer.

Comment: Probably the problem is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096160/error-on-running-sage The Python on your computer should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @kcrisman I build sage 7.6 from source code on the same computer and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes, unfortunately Linux is really, really picky, so even a slight difference in the version from what the binary was built for might lead to trouble.